# How to get key from value in QMultiMap?

Tags: qml, qmultimap

I have QMultiMap as follows:

```
QMultiMap <int, QString> paramIDMap, paramValueMap;
```

My value is "xyz" and i want to take it's key.

Example: `paramIDMap.getkey("xyz")` like this

How to do this?

Expected output should return key.

Comment: Which key? ____

Comment: You can't. That's not what maps are for. Associative containers don't work this way. There could be multiple keys with the same value. Your only option is to iterate over all the keys in the map, and check each key's value, and figure out what to do from there. But if you need to find a key for a value in the map, it means that you're using the wrong container. You should not be using a map, but something else. You will have to figure out, by yourself, which container you can use in order to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: @ LogicStuff It's hashmap so we retrieve hashmap key from it's value. in the same way this qmultimap works . so i have inserted record like paramIDMap.insert(key,value);

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QMultiMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmultimap.html) is intended to store key-value pairs for fast lookup by key where a key can have multiple values. 
The [QList QMap::keys(const T &value) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#keys-1) method which is inherited from QMap, will return a QList of keys for a specific value. That won't be fast lookup and the time complexity would be linear.

```
QMultiMap <int, QString> paramIDMap;
paramIDMap.insert(1,"a");
paramIDMap.insert(1,"b");
paramIDMap.insert(2,"a");
paramIDMap.insert(2,"b");
QList<int> ks = paramIDMap.keys("a");
```

Which `ks` will contain [1,2].

Comment: @cmhacker, just another note: Qt documentation for each class, will not show the inherited methods, and properties if that class is a sub-class. You will find them by clicking ```List of all members, including inherited members``` link which is always below the first table. It seems to be the reason you did not find this method.